# React page freezes on phone/chrome phone view

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React for a website which works fine on my computer but as soon as try to view it from Chromes phone inspection tool it freezes on a button click, CPU spikes over 100%. I deployed the app on my server as well and tried the same thing with my physical phone and the exact same thing happened.

The button click calls the following method:

```
lvlUpAbility(ability) {

        var treeType = ''

        if (ability.tree === 'AAA') {
            treeType = 'aaaSkillPoints'
        } else if (ability.tree === 'BBB') {
            treeType = 'bbbSkillPoints'
        } else if (ability.tree === 'CCC') {
            treeType = 'cccSkillPoints'
        } else if (ability.tree === 'DDD') {
            treeType = 'dddSkillPoints'
        } else if (ability.tree === 'EEE') {
            treeType = 'eeeSkillPoints'
        } else if (ability.tree === 'FFF') {
            treeType = 'fffSkillPoints'
        }

        if (ability.currentLvl < ability.maxLvl && this.state.skillPointsLeft > 0 && this.state[treeType] >= ability.requiredSkillPoints ) {

            const updatedAbilities = this.state.abilities.map(ab => {
                if (ab.id === ability.id) {
                    return { ...ab, currentLvl: ab.currentLvl + 1 }
                }
                return ab
            })

            this.setState({ abilities: updatedAbilities, skillPointsLeft: this.state.skillPointsLeft - 1, [treeType]: this.state[treeType] + 1 })
        }
    }
```

`this.state.abilities` is an array of objects, right now there are 80 entries. Once the method is called, it basically find the right ability in the array and updates the level of it. Does someone know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried running it under the Profiler tool provided by the React Developer Tools chrome extension?